# Errors compiling an example kernel module

Tags: module, kernel

I am trying to compile an example module from the Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide using alternate names for the init and cleanup functions but I keep getting the errors below:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-54-generic/build
 M=/media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3 modules
 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
 CC [M] 
 /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.o In
 file included from
 /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.c:1:0:
 ./include/linux/module.h:129:42: error: redefinition of ‘__inittest’  
 static inline initcall_t __maybe_unused __inittest(void)  \
                                           ^ /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.c:18:1:
 note: in expansion of macro ‘module_init’  module_init(hello_3_exit); 
 ^~~~~~~~~~~ ./include/linux/module.h:129:42: note: previous definition
 of ‘__inittest’ was here   static inline initcall_t __maybe_unused
 __inittest(void)  \
                                           ^ /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.c:17:1:
 note: in expansion of macro ‘module_init’  module_init(hello_3_init); 
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
 /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.c:
 In function ‘__inittest’:
 /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.c:18:13:
 error: return from incompatible pointer type
 [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]  module_init(hello_3_exit);
              ^ ./include/linux/module.h:130:11: note: in definition of macro ‘module_init’   { return initfn; }     \
            ^~~~~~ /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.c:
 At top level: ./include/linux/module.h:131:6: error: redefinition of
 ‘init_module’   int init_module(void) __attribute__((alias(#initfn)));
       ^ /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.c:18:1:
 note: in expansion of macro ‘module_init’  module_init(hello_3_exit); 
 ^~~~~~~~~~~ ./include/linux/module.h:131:6: note: previous definition
 of ‘init_module’ was here   int init_module(void)
 __attribute__((alias(#initfn)));
       ^ /media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.c:17:1:
 note: in expansion of macro ‘module_init’  module_init(hello_3_init); 
 ^~~~~~~~~~~ cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
 scripts/Makefile.build:337: recipe for target
 '/media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.o'
 failed make[2]: ***
 [/media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3/hello-3.o]
 Error 1 Makefile:1552: recipe for target
 '_module_/media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3'
 failed make[1]: ***
 [_module_/media/aaron/GoogleDrive/School/CSC239/project/LKM/hello3]
 Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
 '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic' Makefile:4: recipe for
 target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here are my source and make files:

```c
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>

static int hello3_data __initdata = 3;

static int __init hello_3_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world %d.\n", hello3_data);
        return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_3_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 3.\n");
}

module_init(hello_3_init);
module_init(hello_3_exit);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m := hello-3.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like there is an error in init.h but I can't edit that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your last lines:

```c
module_init(hello_3_init);
module_init(hello_3_exit);
```

You've used `module_init` twice.

Instead, you want to use `module_exit`:

```c
module_init(hello_3_init);
module_exit(hello_3_exit);
```

Hope I'm not too late in answering this!

Answer (score 0):

1. Just check if there are other .c files in same directory !! I solved it after I removed other .c file in current directory
2. Or remember to add `gcc...` in Makefile to compile other .c files